# Loading images from a directory one at a time in tkinter python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter

I need to load the images from a current working directory in GUI that is bound to a button "load next image".
So far, I am only able to load the first image file then it gives me an error.

Below is my code:

```
def NextFile(self):

    currentDirectory = os.getcwd()
    FileNames = os.listdir(currentDirectory)
    images = []
    for name in FileNames:
        if ".gif" in name:
            images.append(name)
            
            self.imageLabel["image"] = self.image = PhotoImage(file = images)
```

I get this error message:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 4006, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "SmallWaterFall.gif smokey.gif": no such file or directory
```

Comment: `images` is a list and so `file = images` is incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

I think it could be because you aren't executing your code in the same path. Try to execute simply like "python3 init.py" in the same path than your program.